# How to count the number of occurrence of column values but without GROUP BY (not distinct values) mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
id      title           numbers
1       chicken         1
2       meat            1
3       fish            1
4       fish            2
5       meat            2
6       fish            3
7       chicken         2
8       chicken         3
```

I want to construct the following output as above. Anyone can help me calculate number of occurrence of column values but without **GROUP BY**(not remove same values) , let create "numbers" field same as above , thank

Normal , if use `COUNT(*)`  :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY title
```

But it remove same values :

```
id      title           numbers
1       chicken         3
2       meat            2
3       fish            3
```

i want to keep same values , and output like this :

```
id      title           numbers
1       chicken         1    
2       meat            1
3       fish            1
4       fish            2
5       meat            2
6       fish            3    
7       chicken         2     
8       chicken         3
```

Comment: your question is unclear. not getting what data u want from which data.

Comment: It would help if you display a portion of the data from your table, and a mock-in screen shot of your desired output.

Comment: Is it clear ? anyone can help me ?

Comment: That is usually done using the `row_number()` window function. MySQL does not support this though. But if you search for "row_number replacement mysql" there are plenty of examples on how kind of simulate this with MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is how to generate the `numbers` column in your sample output.  If that's not correct, please clarify the question.

```
select  id
,       title
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    Table1 t2
        where   t1.title = t2.title
                and t2.id <= t1.id
        ) as numbers
from    Table1 t1
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee7d/2/0)

Comment: @Andomar +1 I was doing without `t2.id <= t1.id` do I got the total count for each ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee7d/16

Comment: No bonCodigo , i want like above , because i want to create new field same as "ordering"

Comment: anyone have another solution for this ?